# Role implementation not picked up by menu list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, menuitem, roles

I am implementing user roles.  I have menu list drawn in HTML and I am controlling the visibility of them from my code behind.  I have 3 database tables, `User w/ User_Number, User_Role_ID`, `Roles w/ Role_ID, Role_Name`, `User_Roles w/ User_Role_ID, User_Number, Role_ID`.  The `Role_ID` is an integer linked to a role name.  Each user is assigned to one of six of these integers and their role is based on this.  All work as expected apart from my `Administrator` role which is int 3.  It will allow me to display or hide any table based on this role, with the exception of `lstAdminMenu`.  I have tested all other roles and menus and I can show any menu in any role except for the `lstAdminMenu` in the `Administrator role`.  The menu contorl is:

```
 <li runat="server" id="lstAdminMenu"><a class="menuitem">Administration</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/CreateStudent.aspx">Create Student</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/EnrollStudent.aspx">Manual Enrollments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/EnrollStudent.aspx">Edit Student</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/CreateStaff.aspx">Create Staff Member</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/CreateAVOS.aspx">Create Advisor</a></li>
                            <li><a  href="../Administrative/AddResults.aspx">Input Grades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/FeesPaid.aspx">Fees</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/NewModulesAndProg.aspx">Create Module</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/AdminEditDegreesModules.aspx">Edit Modules</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/EditStudentStatus.aspx">Student Status</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/MarkModulesAsRunningSuspended.aspx"/>Module Status</li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/AddModuleEvents.aspx">Module Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/PasswordGeneration.aspx">Password Reset</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/Import.aspx">Import</a></li>
                            <li><a href="../Administrative/AddBuildingOrRoom.aspx">Create Estate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                       </li>
```

Code behind:

```
  '' Initialise Admin profile
    Dim Administrator As Boolean
    Administrator = False

     For Each Role As Role In userPermissions
        If Role.Role_ID = 3 Then
            Administrator = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Administrator Then
        lstAdminMenu.Visible = True
        lstAcademics.Visible = False
        lstSeniorUM.Visible = False
        lstAcademicPM.Visible = False
    Else
        lstAdminMenu.Visible = False
    End If
```

Also when I debug this it says that the role is Aministrator and the visibility of `lstAdminMenu` is true.  I cannot get this one figured out at all.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that too many arguments for visibility on the page was causing confliction with the roles.  I have changed all my menus to be hidden by default and each item only shows if the correct user is logged in.  Code is now more like this for each role:

```
  If Administrator Then
    lstAdminMenu.Visible = True
  End If
```